# How to get video resolution on browser/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I need to validate video resolution, if it's above 1280x720, I need to block it before user uploads it. How to do this on browser or javascript?

Comment: Beware some video formats allow for variable video dimensions (e.g vP8 in webm), and this may become more and more common with screencast recordings.

Answer (score 0):

Can use mp4box npm library.

```js
import MP4Box from 'mp4box'

let reader = new FileReader()

const mp4boxfile = MP4Box.createFile();

function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

reader.onload = function() {
  mp4boxfile.onReady = function (info) {
    console.log('Video info: ', info); // resolution info is available on info.videoTracks[0].video.width and .height
  }

  const arrayBuffer = _base64ToArrayBuffer(reader.result.slice(22))
  arrayBuffer.fileStart = 0;
  mp4boxfile.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(videoFile); // videoFile comes from onChange event of input file element
```

Video codec info detail as well as video duration also available on info object.

Comment: Don't convert to base64 here, your FileReader can read to ArrayBuffer directly, and in modern browsers you can even just `await file.arrayBuffer()`